# My brand new raspberry pi 2 b will not start up

Tags: raspbian

When I plug it in the raspberry in has one red and one green led lights up. My first time with raspberry.

Comment: http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please describe how you set up the OS on your SD card? If you find anything useful in the link provided by joan, feel free to tell.

Comment: If you follow http://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151 you should be able to troubleshoot boot problems. @joan the eLinux link is a bit dated, and doesn't directly address B+ or Pi2.

Comment: Do please check out the section on the LEDs in Joan's link - particularly for a number of flashes for the Green LED - that gives important information about how far the Pi has got in booting up.  You MUST have a microSD card with an operating system inserted into the RPi (downloadable from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) if there was not one with the RPi) - I *think* if there is not a Card inserted than the Green LED *will* light up solid green...

Comment: @SlySven *"I think if there is not a Card inserted than the Green LED will light up solid green"* -> A simple premise to test, lol.  Presuming it is true ;| ;| then if you did have a card (properly) inserted, this implies there is a problem with the card.

Comment: But consider the Op's situation - "My first time with raspberry" - they may not realise that one - with an operating system on - is required - some other small size computing devices have a basic OS in a flash device soldered onto the mother board - like the Compute Module with its 4Gbyte eMMC Flash device rather than the other Pis which need a either a normal or mini SD card.  Also not all purchasing opportunities for RPis *include* said Flash card.

Comment: @SlySven I think goldilocks was suggesting YOU could test in 30 seconds. And it is true.

Answer (score 1):

The other guys might have made things a bit hard to understand. Based on what you said, here are some points:

1. Make sure you plugged in an SD card.

   - That exact thing happens when you don't have an SD card installed.
2. Make sure to give the Pi something to start up.

   - A Pi won't work with an empty SD card. That same thing happens when there's nothing to start up.

**Here's how to install NOOBS if your SD card is empty:**

1. [Follow the instructions in this link.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/)

   - Basically what it says is reformat the SD card (FAT32), download the NOOBS zip file, extract it, then copy the extracted files into the SD card. Don't copy the zip file itself.
   - After that's done, plug in a mouse, keyboard, and monitor, power it up, and select an OS to install (Raspbian preferred).
   - After it's done installing, restart. The default username is `pi` and the default password is `raspberry`. If you're in some command line, type `startx` then press enter to get to the desktop.

Comment: I cannot tell you the number of times I have been frustrated with the B 2 because the SD card has popped out and at first glance it is not obvious. To be fair it is always my fault, trying to move the unit around and pushing enough on the SD card to cause it to eject.

Comment: @rob I feel you.